Help with gradient fill in Inkscape
sorry for asking this, but I'm new to Inkscape (or any vector program whatsoever). I'm trying to replicate the following image

however, I can't quite make that particular gradient fill in those two circles. I figured that maybe I should use the radial gradient option, but I can't figure out the controls to make it happen.
Can you help me?

It would be possible to use a radial gradient on a stroke, however it's a little tricky to get a smooth gradient.
Open the stroke paint dialog, select the radial gradient option, and edit the stops as you like.  You can also add stops visually using the gradient tool in the toolbar. Double click on the gradient guides to add stops where you want to place them.
Something like this. I suppose you could add more stops to smooth it out.

Another method would be to blur a circle with a grey stroke, and put it in a clip group made from a thick circle with stroke converted to path.  Like this

